# PHP Preg Replace doesn't work AFTER line break

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Have code that gets a txt file, replaces line breaks, then links and then hashtags.

When a hashtag follows a line break, it does not replace the hashtag. Not sure where in the regrex this is failing.

```
// replace line breaks
$txt = str_replace('&lt;br /&gt;','<br />',$txt);

// replace links
$txt = preg_replace_callback('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', function($m) { return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.substr($m[1], 0, 30).'...</a>'; }, $txt);

// replace hashtags
$txt = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', '<a href="index.php?q=$1">#$1</a>', $txt);
```

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/RPVEW

Comment: @Nick Tried with the line break replace and it fails. Makes me think its the <br /> causing issue. But I don't know in the regex that solves this  https://3v4l.org/OMMPh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<!\S)` means that the character before the hashtag must be a whitespace character (not non-whitespace (`\S`)). The `>` in `<br />` does not meet that requirement. You can probably get away with asserting that the character before the hashtag is not a `word` character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`):

```
$txt = preg_replace('/(?<!\w)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', '<a href="index.php?q=$1">#$1</a>', $txt);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aHED9)